# Align arrays based on same index numbers alone?

Tags: arrays, bash, multidimensional-array, awk

Hello here is my second question regarding arrays and bash scripting. Thanks!!

I have 2 arrays. one array is

```
a[1]
a[2]
a[3]
a[4]
a[5]
a[6]
a[7]
a[8]
a[9]
a[10]
```

The other array is

```
b[1]
b[2]
b[3]
b[4]
b[5]
b[6]
b[7]
b[8]
b[9]
b[10]
```

Is it possible to print/output/align by any way the 2 so that they are aligned as per their index numbers, so that the output is always the same index numbers side by side:

```
a[1] b[1]
a[2] b[2]
a[3] b[3]
a[4] b[4]
a[5] b[5]
a[6] b[6]
a[7] b[7]
a[8] b[8]
a[9] b[9]
a[10] b[10]
```

They are actually both sorted out differently from the start. So in reality the first A array looks like:

```
a[1]
a[2]
a[3]
a[4]
a[5]
a[6]
a[7]
a[8]
a[9]
a[10]
```

and the second one, which is out of the original sort order, is

```
b[2]
b[4]
b[3]
b[5]
b[7]
b[6]
b[9]
b[1]
b[9]
b[8]
```

The actual desired output is aligning the 2 arrays by indexes after messing around with the sorting. So the desired output is the b's after messing with them and I then need the corresponding a's next to them based on INDEX NUMBERS.

```
b[2] a[2]
b[4] a[4]
b[3] a[3]
b[5] a[5]
b[7] a[7]
b[6] a[6]
b[9] a[9]
b[1] a[1]
b[10] a[10]
b[8] a[8]
```

Is this possible in bash/awk ?
This would be so much easier with a simple multidimensional array. I haven't got my head around the single dimensional associative array solution for this situation.

If I had a multidimensional array, I'd just need to always have the 2 values from both columns in the same array but in different dimensions of this same array. That way I could sort by the second dimension and still have the first dimension right next to it for further computing.

At a lack of multidimensional arrays in bash/awk, I am just relying on the index numbers to keep them all aligned but I can't do this because I dont know how to print 2 arrays next to each other with their indexes lined up right.

How do I get around this?

Comment: what do you mean the array is sorted out differently?  Do you mean the iteration order is given by some other means?   In awk you can sort the array and retrieve the index order.  Perhaps asking the actual question not the derivative one will help!?

Comment: Derivative here =)

Comment: bash and awk are completely different tools, each with their own syntax and semantics. Are you asking about bash arrays or awk arrays or something else? Awk arrays are associative and have no specific order associated with their indices so idk what you mean when you say `They are actually both sorted out differently from the start`. FWIW GNU awk has multi-dimensional arrays and you can sort the indices however you like for output with an `in` loop (google `sorted_in`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since awk arrays are not ordered, I am assuming that your 'arrays' are lines from a file.  If that is the case, try:

```
$ awk -F'[][]' 'FNR==NR{a[$2+0]=$0; next} {print $0,a[$2+0]}' filea fileb
b[2] a[2]
b[4] a[4]
b[3] a[3]
b[5] a[5]
b[7] a[7]
b[6] a[6]
b[9] a[9]
b[1] a[1]
b[10] a[10]
b[8] a[8]
```

#### How it works

- `-F'[][]'`

  This tells awk to use `[` and `]` as field separators.  In this way, the number that we are interested in is field 2.
- `FNR==NR{a[$2+0]=$0; next}`

  When reading the first file, we save each line, `$0`, in array `a` under the index of `$2`.  Then, we skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `print $0,a[$2+0]`

  While reading the second file, we print each line from the second file, `$0`, and the value of array `a` under the key of the second field, `$2`.

#### Printing two awk arrays in order

In this example, we use `split` to create to awk arrays and we print then in order:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{split("a b c d",a); split("1 2 3 4",b); for (i=1;i<=length(a);i++)print a[i],b[i]}'
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
```